# Align Text Left and Right Inline (iText7.Html2pdf)

Tags: html, css, itext7

I have some HTML code where I align two spans left and right and this appears properly in the browser with the HTML code but after compiling with iText7 to PDF, the left-aligned text is gone and in its place is the right aligned text (see image 1 and image 2, respectively).

#### image 1 (HTML):

[image: 1. rendered HTML]

#### image 2 (PDF):

[image: 2. rendered PDF]

#### This is the code I have for my HTML:

```
<li id="row1">
    <span class="left bold">left-aligned text</span>
    <span class="right bold">right-aligned text</span>
</li>
```

#### CSS:

```
#row1 {
  position:relative;
  max-width: 6.8in;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

I know iText7 is a little finicky with CSS but I figure there is either a way to simply use this basic CSS functionality or a way to trick/work around iText7 to render it as intended.

Comment: Does trying inline CSS works?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour, yes, ```display:inline;``` works with iText. Is there a way to position it within this?

Comment: No, by inline CSS, I meant something like `<span style="position:absolute;right: 0;">right-aligned text</span>` aka writing CSS with HTML (not in a separate file). And what about just using `float: left;` and `float: right;`?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour so inline CSS doesn't do the trick but float left and right does. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) CSS property to place elements on the left or the right.

So here's your code:

```css
#row1 {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 6.8in;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<li id="row1">
    <span class="left bold">left-aligned text</span>
    <span class="right bold">right-aligned text</span>
</li>
```